# Create "linked clone" or layered shared disks with QEMU

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, libvirt, virt-manager

**Does QEMU support a feature like [VMware's "linked clone"](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-BA264A65-C50F-4345-A787-DCC5C5324DD1.html)?**

What I'm trying to accomplish:  I'm setting up a test environment with a handful of VMs, that are all nearly identical.  However, a fresh Windows install takes over 20 GiB, which would be duplicated for each VM.

In VMware, one would create a "linked clone", which is most likely a copy-on-write layer atop the original disk image.

Can we do this with QEMU?  I'm specifically trying to accomplish this using `virt-manager` (libvirt).

Related:

- [Linked Cloning?](http://www.convirture.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=5250) (convirture.com)

Answer (score 6):

QEMU's primary virtual disk format is QCOW2, which stands for *QEMU Copy-On-Write 2*. It is desiged specifically to enable these kinds of setups.

You can do this manually using `qemu-img`. (Skip directly to the second command if you already have a base image)

```
$ qemu-img create -f qcow2 base-image.qcow2 1M
Formatting 'base-image.qcow2', fmt=qcow2 size=1048576 encryption=off cluster_size=65536 lazy_refcounts=off refcount_bits=16

$ qemu-img create -f qcow2 -b base-image.qcow2 linked-image.qcow2
Formatting 'linked-image.qcow2', fmt=qcow2 size=1048576 backing_file='base-image.qcow2' encryption=off cluster_size=65536 lazy_refcounts=off refcount_bits=16

$ qemu-img info base-image.qcow2
image: base-image.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 1.0M (1048576 bytes)
disk size: 196K
cluster_size: 65536
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    lazy refcounts: false
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false

$ qemu-img info linked-image.qcow2
image: linked-image.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 1.0M (1048576 bytes)
disk size: 196K
cluster_size: 65536
backing file: base-image.qcow2
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    lazy refcounts: false
    refcount bits: 16
```